# My Pygame window only updates when i am moving my cursor around on the window

Tags: python, pygame

My Pygame window will only update if my cursor is moving and is above the window.

```
import pygame

window_length = 1000
window_height = 600
dimensions = (window_length, window_height)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(dimensions)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

main = True

x = 0
y = 0

while main:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main = False
            
        x += 1
            
        #redraw background
        pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (0,0, window_length, window_height))
        pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, (x, y, 100, 100))
        pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I tried moving things around but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unindent the code under the event loop. Right now, you're only doing the drawing code when there are events to loops through, like your mouse moving.

It should look like:

```py
while main:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main = False

    x += 1

    #redraw background
    pygame.draw.rect(window, BLACK, (0,0, window_length, window_height))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, WHITE, (x, y, 100, 100))
    pygame.display.update()
```